# Finding values using the equation of $x$ that satisfies $\left\{ x \right\} + \left\{ {\frac{1}{x}} \right\} = 1$

Tags: functions, fractions

Let the real number $x$ satisfies $\left\{ x \right\} + \left\{ {\frac{1}{x}} \right\} = 1$ and $k$ denotes the value of $\left\{ {{x^3}} \right\} + \left\{ {\frac{1}{{{x^3}}}} \right\} = k$ (where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes
fractional part function). Find the value of $k$.

My approach is as follows: $x$ cannot be an integer,
$x = n + a,a \in \left( 0,1 \right)$

$$a + \left\{ {\frac{1}{{n + a}}} \right\} = 1 \Rightarrow \left\{ {\frac{1}{{n + a}}} \right\} = 1 - a = t,t \in \left( {0,1} \right)$$

Not able to proceed from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint*: Since $\{x\}+\{x^{-1}\}$ is an integer, that means $x+x^{-1}$ is also an integer.  So $x^3+x^{-3}=(x+x^{-1})^3-3(x+x^{-1})$ is also an integer.  Now show $x^3$ is irrational to conclude $\{x^3\}+\{x^{-3}\}=1$.

Comment: Note that this approach works "for any value of $3$", i.e. generalizes to any $\{x^p\}+\{x^{-p}\}=1$ for an integer $p\ne 0$.